# How to validate the form with a file on vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I got a text and file input and i do not know how to include the method of v-on:change to the form submit.

the goal here is when submitting the form i want it to be validated first.

i tried to console.log all the variables inputted on the console browser nothing works.

```
methods:{
        checkForm: function (e){
            e.preventDefault(); 
            this.errors = [];

            if(this.FileName){
                return true;
            }
            if(!this.FileName){
                this.errors.push("File name required");
            }


        },
        OnChangeFile: function(event){
            var fileData =  event.target.files[0];
            this.fileName = fileData.name;  
            this.fileSize = fileData.size;  
            this.fileType = fileData.type;  
            var File_Name = this.fileName;
            var File_Size = this.fileSize;
            var File_Type = this.fileType;
            var MB =  File_Size / 1024 / 1024;            
            if(File_Type == "application/pdf"){
                if(MB < 5){
                    return true;
                    }else{
                        this.errors.push("File size exceed the 10mb limit");
                    }    
            }else{
                this.errors.push("File should be in PDF format.");
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML with the change event?

Comment: <input type="file" name="file" v-on:change="OnChangeFile()">